# Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed or database not closed error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I run  my app fine on my phone which post API 11

However when I run on the emulator (version 2.2 or API 8), I get the following expcetion for my sql lite calls

```
Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed or database not closed error
```

Any idea why or how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are done with the cursor, you need to call `Cursor.close()`. Leaving it not closed leads to memory leaks. E.g.:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(myUri, MY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // moar code
    }
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh really? I am surprised all the examples of sql lite and tutorials never talk about closing it.

Comment: Well, now you got an example that mentions about it :)